# Need a comma separated group by in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table below.

```
ID  Value
12  foo
12  bar
34  foo
45  bar
56  foo
56  bar
```

I wish to have the below

```
ID  Value
12  foo,bar
34  foo
45  bar
56  foo,bar
```

I know how to do it in Python but powerbi is making it difficult for me.
Just to add I am using power bi version 2.65.5313.1421 64 bit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this in **Power Query** by couple of steps stated as below-

**Step-1:** Apply Group on Column **ID** as shown below-

[image]

**Step-2:** Now add a custom column as shown below-

[image]

**Step-3:** Now extract values as below-

[image]

**Step-4:** Select **Comma** as below after selecting the Extract value option-

[image]

**Step-5:** Now you have your desired output (You can remove column1 if required)

[image]

**Here is M query for you for your further reference**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjRS0lFKy89XitWBcpISi8AcYxMkGRNTJBlTMyQZMAcsEwsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Value = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Value", type text}}),

    //--Steps started from here.
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"Column1", each _, type table [ID=nullable number, Value=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each [Column1][Value]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

Comment: After Step 2, they all say "Error" instead of "List". Any ideas?

Comment: FIgured it out. I thought you were using `[Value]` as some sort of call to a key variable named `Value` built into PowerBI, but really, `Value` in your example is actually referencing the Column name. So I just had to change `[Value]` to the name of my soon-to-be-comma-delimited column instead

Comment: How did you obtain the column [Value]? There's a column called ID, and one called Column1, but not one called [Value] so I'm very confused how you added a custom column [Column1][Value] if there's no [Value] column already....